# Naming attributes and methods

Tags: python, pep8

[From PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)

> #### Method Names and Instance Variables
>
> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.

By this PEP guide the following code should be OK.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.set_alarm = object
        self.cancel_alarm = object

    def set_alarm(self):
        pass

    def cancel_alarm(self):
        pass
```

But of course it won't work, what's the advise in such cases? use mixedCase for the function name?

I don't understand why underscore_snake is preferred over mixedCase. In the same pep it states that

> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
> prevailing style

Comment: What do you mean *"won't work"*? What exactly is that supposed to do? The naming conventions are style, not syntax.

Comment: You class works. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Use your imagination...how about naming the non-functions `set_alarm_object` and `cancel_alarm_object` (or something similar that doesn't sound like a function name)?

Comment: it won't work because `self.set_alarm` is either the instance method and the instance attribute. They overlap.

Comment: martineau, yeah I'm doing that, but sometimes this gets rather verbose. That's why I made this question.

Comment: The style guide isn't there to stop you shadowing things. It says you should use `lowercase_with_underscores`, but doesn't say you have to use the same name for everything! Attributes and methods are virtually indistinguishable in Python, you should have clear enough names that this isn't a problem (and use trailing underscores where collisions are otherwise inevitable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's preferred because it's preferred. Casing rules are almost always arbitrary and vary from community to community. The main goal is consistency between various libraries. For instance, without this rule you could have something like this:

```
s.Foo = bar_2.oogaBooga()
s.Bar = BAZ.BAZOID()
q = spam.egg_soup()
```

Where oogaBooga, BAZOID, and egg_soup each come from different libraries. This would make code harder to read.